# Does the mean ratio of the largest prime factor in prime gaps to the lower bound of the gap converge?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

Posting in MO since this questions has been [unanswered in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763331/what-is-the-mean-value-of-the-largest-prime-factor-in-a-prime-gap) for 3 months.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime and $q_n$ be largest among all the prime factors of the composite numbers  between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$. Is it true that there exists some constant $C$ such that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{q_2 + q_3 + \cdots + q_n}{p_2 + p_3 + \cdots + p_n} 
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{q_i}{p_{i}} = C
$$

For $n \le 10^8$, the approximate value of both limits is about $0.2781$ while for $n \le 3.5 \times 10^9$ it is about $0.2747$.

**Update**: **14-Dec-2023**
I evaluated the above ratios for consecutive prime gaps for $p > 10^{40}, p > 10^{50}$ and $p > 10^{60}$ respectively. The limiting value in these tests were $0.2592, 0.2551$ and $0.2511$ which show a very slow decreasing trend.

**Question**: Does the above limit exist? If yes, what does it converge to?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry in advance for potential mistakes. I don't have an answer to the question, but I might have some basic result that is not contradictory with the simulation you carried out.

- Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then, one can notice that $2q_n < p_{n+1}$. Indeed, $q_n$ must divide a composite K number between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$, so that K = $q_nm$, where $m$ is at least $2$.
- Consequently, let $N$ be a positive integer too :$$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{q_n} < \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_{n+1}}$$
  So $$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{q_n} < \frac{1}{2}( \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n} + p_{N+1} - 2)$$
  Hence $$ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{q_n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{p_{N+1}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}} - \frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}}$$
  It is then clear that the important term is $$\frac{p_{N+1}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}}$$
  It is probably bounded, and probably even goes to $0$ when $N$ goes to infinity. However, I have no idea on how to prove it (my assumptions are made by numerical simulations).
  If this result is true, then
- $\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{q_n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}}$ is bounded
- $\displaystyle \limsup_N \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{q_n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}{p_n}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

It might be possible to obtain a refinement of this bound (assuming the assumptions I made were correct) by using the fact that $q_n$ is optimal (I didn't use anywhere the fact that it's the largest prime factor).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The sum over the first $N$ primes is $\Sigma(N)\sim \frac{1}{2} N^{2} \ln N$ (see, e.g., here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) . And $p_{N}\sim N \ln N $ as is well known.